# Formatting string to 10 characters

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am currently working on a project where I need to format a string to be only 10 characters long. But has to start in a certain way and finish with an incrementing counter.

E.G the number will be in the format of:

```
0100000001
0100000002
0100000003
...
0100000010
0100000011
```

I.e. the first two numbers will stay the same only the last digits will keep incrementing but the string has to remain 10 characters long.

How could I do this I have tried using String.Format but doesn't appear to work.

**UPDATE**
I've tried using the following

```
destination = String.Format("07000000{0}", messageCount);
```

This kind of works but once the messageCount gets above 10 the length becomes 11 and it needs to stay no longer than 10

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: what's the input and what have you tried?

Comment: could you use an int counter for the last 8 digits, convert it to a string and then concatenate to the first two numbers (stored as a string)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
String.Format("01{0:00000000}", i);
```

Answer (score 7):

`D8` means format as a decimal with up to 8 leading zeroes

```
string.Format("01{0}", counter.ToString("D8"));
```

Comment: or even simpler: `string.Format("01{0:D8}", messageCount);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var counter = 11;
var fixedPart = "01";
var result = fixedPart + counter.ToString().PadLeft(8,'0');
```

Comment: @DownVoter: Please elaborate, otherwise I can't fix the answer. Anyway, it works like this, I tested it.

Comment: Didn't downvote but guess people object to guiding the OP away from `String.Format()`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `String.Format("00{0:00000000}", num)` ?

See [Custum numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Give this extension method a shot ... I didn't compile it, but let me know if it works :-)

```
public static class Ex
{
  public static string ToSpecialString(this string value)
  {
    int desiredLength = 10;
    string prefix = "01";
    string padding = new String('0', desiredLength - prefix.Length - value.Length);
    return prefix + padding + value;
  }
}

... usage ...

Console.WriteLine( "32".ToSpecialString() );
// should output "0100000032"
```